# Limit dates based on user selection

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have `Leave request form` where the employees are able to request different type of leaves such as paid leave, non paied leave, leave for blood donation etc.
Those types are stored in `Mysql` table and i am visualising them in `dropdown` via this code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="leavetype">Leave type*:</label>
  <select name="leavetype" id="leavetype" required>
    <option disabled selected value="">-- Select--</option> <?php
            include "dbConn.php";
            $records = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT leavetype FROM leavestypes");
            while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
            {
              echo "
        <option value='".$data['leavetype'] ."'>" .$data['leavetype'] ."</option>";
            }
          ?>
  </select>
```

What i want is to limit allowed days, for example if the user select `Leave for blood donation` to be able to use only two days in the date pickers. Here is how the user pick dates:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="startdate">Start:*</label>
  <input required="" class="form-control" name="startdate" id="startdate" type="date">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="tilldate">End:*</label>
  <input required="" class="form-control" name="tilldate" id="tilldate" type="date">
</div>
```

I am trying to limit it via script in the end of the file:

```
<script>
const form = document.querySelector('#leave-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            const startDate = new Date(document.querySelector('#startdate').value);
            const endDate = new Date(document.querySelector('#tilldate').value);
            const leavetype = document.querySelector('#leavetype').value.trim();
            if (endDate < startDate) {
                alert('end date cannot be before start date');
                event.preventDefault();
            } else if (
                leavetype === 'leave for blood donation - two days allowed' ||
                leavetype === 'test2 - two days allowed' ||
                (leavetype === 'leave for marrage - two days allowed ' && ((endDate - startDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) + 1 > 2)) {
                    alert('You can use only two days for this type of leave');
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
</script>
```

I was trying using `includes()` method instead of `===` but not working again.
The problem is that when I have this script if I select some of those type of leaves its always in alert no matter how many days I select in the date picker.

Comment: Logical AND binds stronger than OR - so everything that you "joined" via `||` there in your condition, should be wrapped into `(...)`. `A || B && C` is a _very_ different thing from `(A || B) && C`.

Comment: Btw., comparing the leavetype against those actual _text_ values, is a rather ugly thing to do. Surely your records in the `leavestypes` will have an ID? Then you should use _that_ as the submission value of your options, and then also in your comparison in the JavaScript. (And in whatever table you insert the actual data from this, also belongs that id of the leave type only, and not the actual text. Not sure if you were doing that already or not.)

Comment: Thank you very much. Is now working correctly but I added daysDiff I will post reply with the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed. If someone looking here this is the solution I used:

```
    const form = document.querySelector('#leave-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  const startDate = new Date(document.querySelector('#startdate').value);
  const endDate = new Date(document.querySelector('#tilldate').value);
  const leavetype = document.querySelector('#leavetype').value.trim(); // remove any leading or trailing whitespace
  const daysDiff = (endDate - startDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) + 1;
  if (endDate < startDate) {
    alert('Крайната дата не може да бъде преди началната');
    event.preventDefault();
  } else if (daysDiff > 2 && (leavetype === 'leave for blood donation - two days allowed' || 
  leavetype === 'test2-  two days allowed' ||
  leavetype === 'leave for marrage - two days allowed ')) {
    alert('Можете да поискате максимум 2 дни за този тип отсъствие');
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to group the "OR" with a parenthesis in your else-if statement

Because in your example, it triggers when :

- `leavetype === 'leave for blood donation - two days allowed'`
- `leavetype === 'test2 - two days allowed'`
- `(leavetype ==='leave for marrage - two days allowed ' && ((endDate - startDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) + 1 > 2)`

I'm guessing what you wanted to do is this:

```js
else if (
    (leavetype === 'leave for blood donation - two days allowed' || 
     leavetype === 'test2 - two days allowed' ||
     leavetype ==='leave for marrage - two days allowed ') &&
    ((endDate-startDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) + 1 > 2)
) {
    alert('You can use only two days for this type of leave');
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

Comment: Problem solved with this: 
} else if (daysDiff > 2 && (leavetype =='.............')) {
    alert('You can use only two days for this type of leave');
    event.preventDefault();